# update table by value in other table which holds multiple records

Tags: sql-server

I've seen couple of similar questions containing update table by value on another table.

But if T2 holds multiple records with that same aid and also only update records in T1 that have status = O?

```
T1
aid = 2345|Status = O
aid = 2120|Status = B


T2
aid = 2345|Status=B|Date=23/12/2002
aid = 2345|Status=F|Date=11/05/2002
aid = 2345|Status=G|Date=4/04/2002
aid = 2345|Status=R|Date=12/03/2002
aid = 2120|Status=G|Date=4/04/2012
aid = 2120|Status=R|Date=12/03/2005
```

Example:

```
 UPDATE T1
    SET T1.Status = T2.Status
    Where T1.aid = (T2.aid of the record that holds newest date or max date)
    AND = T1.Status = 'O'
```

Comment: For T2 are those multiple records or one long concatenation in a single record?

Comment: What value do you want it to update to since there are multiple status values in T2?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @sgeddes it looks like T2 has a date associated with each aid/status pairing and the OP wants the status associated with the max date.

Comment: thald would be this record: aid = 2345|Status=B|Date=23/12/2002 because it is the newest record.

Comment: damn ! I forgotted one thing, only want to update records on T1 that have status = O. I have now updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, for SQL Server 2005+ you can do the following:

**UPDATED**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY aid ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM Table2
)
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Status = T2.Status
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN CTE T2
    ON T1.aid = T2.aid
WHERE T2.RN = 1
AND T1.Status = 'O' -- for your "updated" question
```

---

And another way would be:

```
UPDATE  T1
SET     T1.Status = COALESCE(
          ( SELECT TOP (1) 
                     T2.Status
            FROM     T2
            WHERE    T2.aid = T1.aid
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC
          ), T1.Status)
FROM    T1
WHERE   T1.Status = 'O' ;
```

Comment: Does this return ONE record (newest) from Table2 ?

Comment: @agh This doesn't return rows at all, is an `UPDATE`, but yes, it is using only the newest row from `Table2`; that's what the `T2.RN = 1` is doing :-)

Comment: @agh I updated my answer for your new requirement (even if I think that it wasn't much of a new requirement at all)

Answer (score 2):

Typically you use a `JOIN` to `UPDATE` from multiple tables and then you can use MAX and JOIN table 2 on itself:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Status = b.Status
FROM T1 a 
    JOIN T2 b ON a.aid = b.aid
    JOIN (
        SELECT aid, MAX(date) maxdate
        FROM T2
        GROUP BY aid
    ) c ON b.aid = c.aid AND b.date = c.maxdate
```

Comment: I just have table a and table b. Table a doesn't have date column, just table b. Table b has multiple records with same aid.

Comment: @agh -- table a doesn't have date column in query above, just T2

Comment: He doesn't use a date column associated with table a. This is correct for non-CTE solution.

Comment: Hi sgeddes. I forgotted that i only want to update record in T1 that have status = O. I tested your solution and it's only updating one record on T1 but i´m running this on couple of hundred rows that should be updating.